# Very simple sort algorithm not working

Tags: java, sorting

```
public static int[] sortArr(int[] a){
    int temp;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[findMin(a, i)];
        a[findMin(a, i)] = temp;
    }
    return a;
}
public static int findMin(int[] a, int start){
    int min = a[start];
    int minIndex= start;
    for(int i = start; i < a.length; i++){
        if(a[i] < min){
            min = a[i];
            minIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return minIndex;
}
```

the sortArr method just returns the array that it is given, and I can't see why.  I've worked it out on paper and it should be working.  Can anybody see the problem?

Comment: Which variable do you return in `findMin()`, `min` or `minIndex`?

Comment: I just edited it, i return minIndex to find the location of the smallest value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're calling `findMin` twice, but the code on the same line as the first call is causing the result of the second call to change.

You have:

```
a[i] = a[findMin(a, i)]; // findMin() returns the min, and you'll move that to a[i]
a[findMin(a, i)] = temp; // findMin() returns the new min == i
```

Instead use:

```
int min = findMin(a, i);
a[i] = a[min];
a[min] = temp;
```